# Understanding Virtual Velocities in Delta Robot Dynamics Modeling

Tags: dynamics, robot, parallel

I want to model the dynamics of a delta robot, and I came across this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235340613_Recursive_modelling_in_dynamics_of_Delta_parallel_robot). It utilizes the Newton-Euler method with virtual work to derive the equations. There's a section called *Simulation Procedure* that provides a step-by-step explanation of how to solve these equations.

I've followed all the steps, but I'm stuck on the last one. For the final step, I'm unsure about what values to assign to $w_{21a}^{Av}$, $w_{32a}^{Av}$, $w_{54a}^{Av}$, $w_{21a}^{Bv}$, and so on. The article previously mentioned that these variables represent virtual velocities and the author assumed $w_{10a}^{Av}=1$, $w_{10a}^{Bv}=0$, and $w_{10a}^{Cv}=0$, but there is no information provided regarding the other virtual velocities.

I'm not very familiar with the virtual work method. I understand that there's a virtual path involved, and the other virtual variables are derived from that, but I'm struggling to grasp how this information helps in finding the equations.

[image]